# Python - I need a specific way of making multi-line input

Tags: python, text, input, line, break

I need a to make multi-line input in Python.
This is part of my program:

```
input_ = input("Enter text:\n") #This can handle only single line of text
```

Like this:

```
Enter text:

This is frst line, #Variable input_ would be only this line
this is second line,
this is last line.
```

> I need something that would ask user to enter text (multi-line text)
>   and when user Paste text (Ctrl + C) and he press Enter, program
>   needs to put whole text into a list.

P.S. Please don't mark this as duplicate, because it's a little diffrent than other questions that doesn't help me.

Comment: How would you know when the input is over?

Comment: Input is over when user press Enter.

Comment: In multi line input, you would have a newline character (enter) after each line. How would you distinguish that from the "user entered enter that ends input" ?

Comment: User needs to **paste** text, once enter is pressed input is over.

Comment: See my answer below Ante. The user can paste and then hit enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a while loop:

```
listed = []
inputs = None

while inputs != '':
    inputs = input()
    listed.append(inputs)

listed = [i for i in listed if i != '']
print listed
```

Comment: What if I enter "some paragraph\n\nsome paragraph"?

Comment: It should work fine until an empty input.

Comment: But user needs to press enter twice after an input, can i fix that somehow ?

Comment: No, this is as close as you can get to handle the multiline input.

Comment: Ok, can you edit your code that saves text into list (1 line = 1 list item)

Comment: How's this? Be sure to mark as answer.

Comment: It works, but i need 1 more thing, how to remove empty item ('') from the list ? Do I need to do that after input is done ?